# Pass LatLng from google maps click event to rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I'm working on an app using google maps. I'm trying to give users the ability to long press a location and have a marker for that location appear, then in that markers infowindow there will be links for directions(next iteration) and to add that location as a saved area, which I'm currently working on. I have the code

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousedown', function(event){

      var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000);
      var latLng=event.latLng;
      var contentString= '<%= link_to "Add Parking Area", free_parking_areas_path(latLng), method: :post, id: "pass_latLng"%>'
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseup', function(event){
          clearInterval(counter);
        });

      function timer(){
        count=count-1;
        if (count <= 0)
        {
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latLng,
              map: map,
              title: "Unsaved Marker"
            });

            marker.addListener("click", function(){
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
           return;
        }
      }
  });
```

but that just throws an error `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method 'latLng' for #<#<Class:0x007fdee654f688>:0x007fdeeb1f16d0>):`. Any idea how I could pass that javascript variable to my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rails `link_to` helper is rendered long before the javascript ever gets executed, thus the javascript `latlng` variable will never get set when the `link_to` helper generates the html link.

You will either need to manually set your link in the JS or use an external source like either of these (or others):

- JS Routes: https://github.com/railsware/js-routes
- Gon: https://github.com/gazay/gon

to expose your server-side data/routes to the client site.

Hope that helps!